# Instagram follower scraping with Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am a beginner in programming, and I try to write a script each week. For my first script, I am trying to develop a bot which goes to my [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram) account and get a list of my followers vs. the people I am following in order to know which people I follow that don't follow me back.

To do so, I used the Selenium package. However, I am stuck in the part where I open the follower box, and I don't know how to proceed to tell to the script to read the data in the dialog and catch the username of the followers and then put it in a list. I tried with an XPath expression and a CSS selector, but I'm getting it wrong.

How can I proceed?

I want to highlight that it's my first code, so it's not clean at all.

Here is my code:

I switched my real username and password for privacy

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#Configuration du driver

username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))



def main():

#Open Driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
    time.sleep(3)
 #Accept Cookies
    cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Autoriser tous les cookies']")
    cookie_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
#Login
    login_username = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'username').send_keys(username)
    login_password = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'password').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element(By.NAME,'password').send_keys('\ue007')
    time.sleep(10)

#Profile
    profile = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[alt*="'+ username + '"]')
    profile.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    followerbox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[href*="/' + username + '/followers/"]')
    followerbox.click()
    time.sleep(10)
#Follower scrapping

    css_selector = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[role=dialog]')


    time.sleep(20)


    close_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'_abl-').click()




#Following scrapping

    time.sleep(3)
    followingbox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[href*="/' + username + '/following/"]')
    followingbox.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    close_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'_abl-').click()
    time.sleep(20)

main()
```

Comment: Doesn't IG have an API you can use instead of scraping?

Comment: Besides @Barmar suggestion, I would also add that scraping someone's site is a good way to get banned. Check their TOS for more info.

Comment: @SiKing yes I am aware of the risk, I have created an account dedicated to that.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I checked and apparently it's more dedicated for creators (I might have not understood the full documentation)

Comment: *[scrapping](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrap#Verb)* != *[scraping](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrape#Verb)*